# Angular Build Error - Injectable calls 'emake decorator'

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, circleci

When i try to build my Angular (8.2.2) application in production mode, it throws the following error:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'Compiler'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'Injectable'
    'Injectable' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.
```

I've tried going back to versions of the code that I know worked previously but for some reason, all of them are throwing this error. It occurs on both my development machines and also on CircleCI so it doesn't seem to be fixable by deleting the node_modules and package-lock.

I can't seem to find any information about this specific error online as most similar errors are about Angular libraries. I'd greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Search for `@Injectable` decorators in your project. Do you have any complex `@Injectable` decorators that you're passing values into?

Comment: @Noremac All of my @ Injectable decorators are either the standard @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
}) or just @ Injectable()

Comment: U might have derieved from a base class and left the @Injectable decorator on the base.service.ts for example

Comment: @Sagat, I do have a base service that is also injectable but that has worked for the past 8 months without problems. Has something in Angular recently changed that no longer allows for it?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix this myself in the end.

One of my own typescript libraries that I was using in my Angular project had a bunch of Angular dependencies by accident. Not sure how they got there but removing them from the package.json file fixed this problem